# Manipulate Silverlight in automated-tests (possible?)

Tags: windows, silverlight, automated-tests

Is manipulate Silverlight in automated-tests possible? If yes - How can I do that? Alternatively can I find anywhere helpful information?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used WebAII from Telerik before:

http://www.telerik.com/products/web-testing-tools/webaii-framework-features.aspx

Pretty good product and allows you to write C# tests which will control a Silverlight application.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I see the problem, that I want to test silverlight-code, that I have not written by myself. I want test a ready website. Have you still other ideas?

Comment: I see no problem with the WebAII Framework.  It doesn't care about if you wrote the code or not, but allows you to write code to automate a silverlight application.